# Cleanup of resources Wicket 6

Tags: java, wicket, listeners, wicket-6

In Java Wicket 6, I'm trying to find out how to get notified in a Page or Component when that Page / component is no longer used.

The context is I have a configuration service that can have listeners added to it to notify when configuration has changed / reloaded.

Obviously, if a page/component is no longer needed then I should remove it as a listener from the service, but I can't find a way of being notified or that fact.

onRemove() doesn't cut it, as it doesn't appear to be called on the page or components in the page since I'm not explicitly REMOVING anything. I'm just letting pages/components drift away into the ether.

Any ideas on how I can clean up my resources to make sure my listener list / memory footprint doesn't balloon over a period of time?

My pages are stateful, btw (although I'm not sure they need to be atm). The Configuration Service is injected into a Page/Component via @SpringBean.

One possible way to propagate a configuration update it to have the page listen ONLY and then fire a Wicket event to contained components. This would cut down on the number of listeners to the Service, but this doesn't FEEL very nice if the components have a reference to the Configuration Service anyway to then be told by something else that it needs to reconfigure. Maybe.

Even so, with the above solution I'd still like to clear the Page from the listener list when no longer needed.

Comment: Are you using WebSockets? Otherwise it doesn't make sense to register a page as a listener to a service: Wicket (or the Container) might serialize/deserialize the page and the registration is lost. Furthermore, what should the page do once it is notified?

Comment: Not using Websockets - I'm not sure how that's relevant. "Furthermore, what should the page do once it is notified?" - rerender based on new changed config - e.g. Displayed TimeZone for dates. The ConfigService itself is Serializable and a can be a member of the component being serialized, so since this is not stored in a detachable model, the service would be serialized also.

Comment: How do you trigger the re-rendering ? The WebSocket would help with this. Without WebSocket you need to tell the browser to issue an HTTP request to re-render a Page/Component

Comment: That's done via an AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior.

Comment: So your page is polling anyway? Then you should just check for updates from your service and update components as needed. No listeners needed.

Comment: Yes I could, although it's unfortunate to have to confuse the reconfiguring of the members within the hierarchy with what is essentially an update on the UI thread. It would work, though - you're right. Doesn't answer my question about knowing when resources are cleaned up, though ;)

Answer (score 1):

By using `@SpringBean` you do **not** make a hard reference between the Page/Component and the real service instance!

`@SpringBean` injects a (serializable) Proxy that has logic to lookup the Spring bean from Spring's ApplicationContext. So I think you have nothing to clean actually.

Comment: If I have a method on the Configuration Service named addConfigChangeListener(pageOrComponentThatIsAConfigChangeListener) the actual service instance will still have a reference to the listener implementing class that should be cleaned up, proxy or no proxy - assuming internally it's just a list of listeners